# Why are my SelectField and RadioField never validate?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to build a very simple form with Flask (0.12), WtForms (2.1) and SQLAlchemy (1.1.5).

form.py :

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField, RadioField, SelectField, IntegerField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from app.models.theme import Theme
from app.models.type import Type
from app.models.user import User

class CreateFolderForm(Form):
    responsible = SelectField('Responsible', choices=User.form_list())
    anomaly_type = SelectField('Anomaly type', choices=Type.form_list())
    theme = SelectField('Theme', choices=Theme.form_list())
    corrective_needed = BooleanField('Corrective action needed')
    cost = IntegerField('Cost')
    risk_level = RadioField('risk level', choices=[(1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'), ])
    risk_occurrence = RadioField('risk occurrence', choices=[(1, '1'), (2, '2'), (3, '3'), ])
    submit = SubmitField('Create')
```

template.html :

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>New Folder</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="" method="post" name="new folder">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            Responsible : {{ form.responsible }} <br/>
            Anomaly Type : {{ form.anomaly_type }} <br/>
            Theme : {{ form.theme }} <br/>
            Corrective Action needed : {{ form.corrective_needed }} <br/>
            Cost : {{ form.cost }}<br/>
            Risk Level : {{ form.risk_level }}<br/>
            Occurrence Level : {{  form.risk_occurrence  }}<br/>
            {{ form.submit }}
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

controller.py :

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import redirect, url_for, flash
from app import app
from flask import render_template
from app import db
from app.models.qualityFolder import QualityFolder
from app.models.user import User
from app.forms.create_folder_form import CreateFolderForm

@app.route('/folder/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_folder():
    form = CreateFolderForm()
    print(form.responsible.validate(form))
    print(form.responsible.errors)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form)
        folder = QualityFolder()
        folder.anomaly_type_id = int(form.anomaly_type.data)
        folder.corrective_action_wanted = form.corrective_needed.data
        folder.cost = int(form.cost.data)
        folder.creation_date = datetime.now()
        if form.credit.data:
            folder.credit = int(form.credit.data)
        folder.risk_level = int(form.risk_level.data)
        folder.occurrence_level = int(form.risk_occurrence)
        db.session.add(folder)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('create/folder_form.html', title='New Folder', form=form)
```

`form.responsible.validate(form)` returns me `False`, but `print(form.responsible.errors)` returns me an empty list. I've the same issue for "anomaly type", "theme", "risk level" and "risk occurrence".

NB: the `form_list` methods are all as below:

```
@staticmethod
def form_list():
    themes = Theme.query.all()
    themes_list = []
    for theme in themes:
        themes_list.append([theme.id, theme.label])
    return themes_list
```

Why isn't my form "validate_on_submit", and do my fields return me "False" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [WTForms docs](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField):

> Note that the choices keyword is only evaluated once, so if you want
>   to make a dynamic drop-down list, you’ll want to assign the choices
>   list to the field after instantiation.

Based on the docs page example, you have to do something like this:

```
class CreateFolderForm(Form):
    responsible = SelectField('Responsible', coerce=int)
```

and

```
@app.route('/folder/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_folder():
    form = CreateFolderForm()
    form.responsible.choices = User.form_list()
    ...
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ...
```

One more thing - `choices` expects a `tuple` while you are currently providing it a with `list`; update `form_list`

```
@staticmethod
def form_list():
    return [
        (theme.id, theme.label) for theme in Theme.query.all()
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks, actually the coerce=int did the job. I'll invest the documentation to find out why it's needed.